# Panel Data Estimation and Control Variables

Tags: mixed-model, econometrics, stata, fixed-effects-model, pooling

My undergrad thesis has something to do with the relationship between emissions, mitigation-related official development assistance, and governance variables in chosen ASEAN countries. As such, my (unbalanced) dataset involves 9 countries and around 10-14 years worth of data according to estimated models. My variables include:

indep:

- mitigation aid (5 lags),
- control of corruption/rule of law
- interaction between the two (mitigation aid * control of corruption, 5 lags)

controls:

- lngdpc,
- lngdpc^2,
- (exports+imports)/gdp,
- forest area % of land area (?),
- and energy intensity/renewable energy consumption(?)`

My options include fixed-effects, random-effects, and pooled OLS. The last two controls are new additions. Intuitively, I know that before the inclusion of these two variables, I'd go with a fixed effects model because the error term is very obviously correlated with my X (say, energy intensity and lngdpc). The Hausman test, however, suggested that I should go with random-effects (Ho) even with so few controls.

Upon including the latter two controls, particularly either energy intensity or renewable energy consumption, the Hausman test varies. Controlling for energy intensity leads to the alternative hypothesis (and insignificant key variables), while controlling for renewable energy consumption leads to the null hypothesis. Controlling for the latter also leads to the Breusch-Pagan LM test to suggest that pooled OLS might be more appropriate. Signs also vary (ex: negative forest area for fixed-effects, positive for random-effects).

How might one go about this, considering that data availability limits the amount of controls I can use and signs cease to follow hypothesized outcomes?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to approach the question of how to model this data set in a different way.  Consider the purpose of each of the types of variables in your problem:

**Dependent variable**:  The thing that is being modeled which is affected by the independent variables.

**Fixed Effect**:  Independent variable which affects the dependent variable and are things which the researcher wishes to test for.  Does the fixed effect have a statistically significant relationship with the dependent variable?

**Control**:  Independent variable which affects the dependent variable, but for which there will be no statistical tests.  Control variables are assumed to have an effect on the outcome.

**Random Effect**:  Independent variable which affects the variance of the dependent variable, but not the expected value in the presence of controls and fixed effects.  (Patient ID number is the classic random effect in a clinical trial)

After you understand how you want to represent each variable, then you can determine if a fixed effects or random effects model is appropriate.  In the case you described, time might also be a factor in your model which might also lead to a time-series analysis.

Be careful conducting too many statistical tests with your data during the exploratory data analysis phase.  Create the model you believe to describe the phenomenon and that will allow for the right hypothesis test or tests, ensure the assumptions of that model are met, and once you have a model that fits well, then test the hypothesis of interest.